# how to not continue a string after 1 for loop cycle using end=""

Tags: python

I have been working on some code within python, and im trying to have a end="" print out a whole list on the same line. the list will then receive more values and delete the old ones. i want these new values to be printed on a new line, and i want to print the whole list on one line. then once again i would like the values to be deleted and new ones to be added, in a loop until all the values have been used. heres the code i wrote

```
 def print_deck():
        Deck=generate_deck()
        Print_Deck=[]
        j=0
        if j<53:
            for k in range(13):
                for i in range(4):
                    print(Deck[j], end="   ")
                    j=j+1
```

when i run my script i get everything on one line, though im trying to only have 4 values from the list per line. here is the output

king of Spades   King of Clubs   King of Diamonds   King of Hearts   Queen of Spades   Queen of Clubs   Queen of Diamonds   Queen of Hearts   Jack of Spades   Jack of Clubs   Jack of Diamonds   Jack of Hearts   Ace of Spades   Ace of Clubs   Ace of Diamonds   Ace of Hearts   2 of Spades   2 of Clubs   2 of Diamonds   2 of Hearts   3 of Spades   3 of Clubs   3 of Diamonds   3 of Hearts   4 of Spades   4 of Clubs   4 of Diamonds   4 of Hearts   5 of Spades   5 of Clubs   5 of Diamonds   5 of Hearts   6 of Spades   6 of Clubs   6 of Diamonds   6 of Hearts   7 of Spades   7 of Clubs   7 of Diamonds   7 of Hearts   8 of Spades   8 of Clubs   8 of Diamonds   8 of Hearts   9 of Spades   9 of Clubs   9 of Diamonds   9 of Hearts   10 of Spades   10 of Clubs   10 of Diamonds   10 of Hearts

I would like it like this:

king of Spades   King of Clubs   King of Diamonds   King of Hearts
Queen of Spades   Queen of Clubs   Queen of Diamonds   Queen of Hearts
Jack of Spades   Jack of Clubs   Jack of Diamonds   Jack of Hearts
Ace of Spades   Ace of Clubs   Ace of Diamonds   Ace of Hearts
ect ect

Any help would be amazing, ive been sitting here for the past 4 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: I suspect you actually want `if j in range(4,5,4)` instead of `j == range(4,52,4)`

Comment: Just put a `print()` line where you want the line break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you wanted was something like this:

```
def print_deck():
  Deck=generate_deck()
  Print_Deck=[]    
  j=0
  for k in range(13):
    for i in range(4):
      print(Deck[j], end="   ")
      j=j+1
    print(" ")
```

also the `if j < 53:` is unneccessary as the previous line sets `j` value to zero

Comment: thanks so much for this, instantly fixed my function. just wondering does putting print(" ") after the 2nd for loop in the 1st for loop stop the end=" " from adding more strings to the current

Comment: @JarrahBaldwinCaesar The `end` statement allows you to use a custom ending character, in this case you were using three spaces. The default ending character for the `print()` function is `\n`. You can see this in the python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: @JarrahBaldwinCaesar If my answer solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.